# How do I fix sum of digits of a number code not entering an infinite loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand why it enters an infinite loop. I stated that: if a % 10 == 0: it should break the loop but it doesn't seem to do so. Could someone explain why this happens and why it is not correct and the solution. Thank you!

```
a = int(input())
total = 0
while a>0:
    rest = a % 10
    total += rest
    if rest == 0:
        break

print(total)
```

Comment: Assume `a % 10` is not 0. How is it ever going to become 0?

Comment: I was thinking, the loop will keep executing until the remainder of the division is 0

Comment: It will. But the remainder will never become 0 (because `a` will never change).

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew what the code was attempting to do.

Comment: Suppose you have 123, you need to find out the sum of the digits.

Comment: That's what I thought but the `if rest == 0: break` part threw me off. FYI, you could do `sum(int(i) for i in str(a))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is running for infinite times because of logical error. value of `a` is not decreasing.
you are checking for remainder, suppose value of a is 230. then at first iteration rest will be 0 and your output will be also 0 (correct sum will be 5).

correct code will be :-

```
a = int(input())
total = 0
while a>0:
    rest = a % 10
    total += rest
    a=a//10
print(total)
```